# How add add class instances to a list

Tags: python, list, class

I'm trying to get a bit better in classes. I want to add multiple cars (with attributes like plate number and time (it is for a security cam)) to a list. I had it working actually, but now it suddenly doesn't and I have no idea what is going on.

```
class CarID:
  def __init__(self, camera, cartime, plate):
    self.camera = camera
    self.plate = plate
    self.cartime = cartime

class Cars:
  def __init__(self):
    self.cars = []

  def addCar(self, car):
    self.cars.append(car)
```

Main Program:

```
def make_lists_cars(data):
  car_list = Cars()
  with open(data, newline='') as f:
    f = f.readlines()
    for line in f[2:-2]:
        car = line.split("\t") 
        camera = car[0]
        cartime = car[1]
        plate = car[2]
        car_list.addCar(CarID(camera, cartime, plate))
  return car_list


data = 'verkeer.txt'
car_list = make_lists_cars(data)
print(Cars().cars)
```

This gives me just an empty list. The car variables all look like ['1', '09:01:53', '2-ABC-32\n']. I actually want to have a list with cars with attributes.
I had it working a couple of hours ago, but then I wanted to add a second list and now it stopepd working :(.
Also do I have to return the car_list, or is this not necessary?

Thanks

Comment: I would suspect the file parsing.

Comment: @StephenRauch, you'd be right in general, but I'm pretty sure it's the new instance in `print(Cars().cars)`

Comment: I suggest adding a `__str__()` method to your classes. This will allow you to do something like `print(car_list)`.

Answer (score 3):

`Cars().cars` is accessing the attribute `cars` from a new instance of `Cars`. `Cars()` in the last line of your code has just been initialized, and no `CarId` objects have been added to the `cars` attribute of `Cars()`. Instead, lookup `cars` from the returned result of `make_lists_cars`:

```
print(car_list.cars)
```

Comment: I changed your terminology a tad. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not at all. The answer is greatly improved.

Comment: Ok thank you, this works. But car_list and Cars() refer to the same class right? So why can't you do a direct 'Cars().addCar' command

Comment: @JordySchep no. `car_list` is an *instance* of the class `Cars`, and the expression `Cars()` is calling the class-object, `Cars`, which returns a *new instance* of that class. You wouldn't expect `x = list()` and `y = list()` to create the same list instance, would you?

Comment: @JordySchep `car_list` and `Cars()` are instances of the class `Car`, which means that any operation applied to one instance will not affect any other instance.

Comment: @JordySchep It might help to think of a class as a recipe of how to build an object. When you do `car_list = Cars()`, Python follows that recipe to build the thing it describes. `Cars` is the recipe (the class). `car_list` is the thing (the instance). So saying "`car_list` and `Cars()`" refers to the same class doesn't make much sense because they do not refer to the recipe but to objects created by following that recipe.